# Using the FFT to get the Fourier transform of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying to use an FFT to numerically obtain the Fourier transform of the function

$ f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\pi}}} \exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2} (\mu x)^2 \right) $

which is precidely

$F(\omega) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\mu \sqrt{\pi}}} \exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2} ( \omega/\mu)^2 \right) $

Note that the input function is real and symmetric and thus I expect the Fourier transform to be real.

To do the Fourier transform I do the following using numpy:

```
x0 = 20
dx = 0.2
N = 1601
x = np.linspace(-20,20,N)
dx = x[1]-x[0]
mu = 2.0
k0 = 0.0

def norm_gaussian(x,mu=1.0, k0=0.0):
    """Defines a normalized Gaussian"""
    return np.exp(-0.5*(x*mu)**2)/np.sqrt(np.sqrt(np.pi)/mu)*np.exp(1j*k0*x)
# Generate the y vector
y = norm_gaussian(x,mu=mu,k0=k0)
# Do the Fourier transform
yt = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y,norm="ortho"))
kt = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(len(x),dx))*2*np.pi
scale = np.sqrt(dx/dk)
ytt = scale*((-1)**np.arange(len(yt)))*yt # Get rid of the (-1)^k
dk = kt[1]-kt[0]
```

Now here is a plot of the Gaussian in t space [Gaussian in t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XAME.png)

Here is a plot of what I get from the FFT [Gaussian in omega](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GguP9.png)
The blue dots are the real part, the green line is the imaginary part, and the orange line is $F(\omega)$.

Note that there is a very significant imaginary part that should not be there.
Is there something that I am doing wrong? I would have expected the imaginary part to be zero simply from symmetry considerations.

Comment: I'm not reading your code very carefully, but it might be because you're computing the DFT of a time-shifted function, which has the effect of multiplying the DFT by $e^{i kt}$ for some $k$.  Try centering your gaussian at index 0 (that is, cyclically shift your current array to the left by around 800 steps).

Comment: ^This. A shift in the time domain is a rotation (by multiplying $e^{ikt}$) in the frequency domain.